# Android Gradle applicationId setting causing "No resource found" in themes.xml

Tags: android, build, android-studio

I converted the Open-Source [Google Authenticator](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-android) from the existing Eclipse project to a Gradle-based Android Studio project. The project builds fine after the conversion. I made the fully working Android Studio project available on [GitHub](https://github.com/capi/google-authenticator-android/commit/03c8d14036d326706e194f720357ba35918433f7).

However, I now changed the `applicationId` in `build.gradle` to another ID in order to be able to install it alongside my productive Google Authenticator on my device. According to my understanding of [ApplicationId versus PackageName](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) this should be the way to go.

The `build.gradle` now looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "invalid.mydomain.project"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 14

        testApplicationId "invalid.mydomain.project.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

while the `AndroidManifest.xml` contains the old package name:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.google.android.apps.authenticator2"
          android:versionCode="21" android:versionName="2.21">
...
```

When doing the Gradle build now, this results in an error, that a resource cannot be found with the package's name:

```
:app:processDebugResources
E:\Martin\Projects\google-authenticator-android\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values\values.xml:199: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'com.google.android.apps.authenticator2:color'.

E:\Martin\Projects\google-authenticator-android\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:16: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'com.google.android.apps.authenticator2:color'.
```

The command that is actually failing is:

```
D:\java_dev\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I D:\java_dev\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-14\android.jar -M E:\Martin\Projects\google-authenticator-android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S E:\Martin\Projects\google-authenticator-android\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A E:\Martin\Projects\google-authenticator-android\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J E:\Martin\Projects\google-authenticator-android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F E:\Martin\Projects\google-authenticator-android\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.google.android.apps.authenticator2 -0 apk
```

My question now is, is this expected behavior and do I now really need to search/replace the package name in the `*.xml` files? From my understanding, this is exactly what `ApplicationId` attempts to avoid.

Is this maybe an issue with Android SDK Build Tools, not in Android Studio?

I reproduced the issue on a clean checkout of the code I provided on both Windows and Linux, so it *should* not be OS-related.

Comment: Maybe you could try to delete the build folder as it is mostly contains compiled files. It seems that gradle is using the old package-identifier for referencing src-related information, which is good

Comment: `gradle clean` and manually deleting build folders doesn't change anything. It seems the `applicationId` is used over the `packageName` when resolving colors, maybe even other resources?

Comment: Why do you think that the applicationID is used? It states that it cant fand the color within the package, not within the applicationId-domain...
Are you sure you added all dependencies to your build.gradle?

Comment: Because it happenes if I change the `ApplicationId` in `build.gradle`, I didn't change the package name. As this is what I understood whould be the easiest way to get the APK to compile with different ID so I can install it alongside existing application, at least to my understanding of http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename  -- And this is the _only_ change, if the `applicationId` is not changed, everything compiles as it should.

Comment: I think your understanding is right. Maybe you could also try to invalidate the cache of android studio and restart it? If you left the package unchanged and only added a applicationID, it should compile fine... at least thats what I would expect :/

Comment: Invalidating the cache folder didn't help. I updated my question with the command that is actually failing. It almost seems as if this could be an issue with the Android SDK / Build Chain, because it states the correct package name on the command line as "special package name".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69632/discussion-between-martin-c-and-degill).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could now narrow it down to `themes.xml`:

```
<style name="AccountListWithVerificationCodesRowCountdownIndicator">
  <item name="com.google.android.apps.authenticator2:color">@color/countdown_indicator</item>
</style>
```

It seems that this hardcodes the `applicationId`, not the `packageName`. Removing the qualification and using

```
<style name="AccountListWithVerificationCodesRowCountdownIndicator">
  <item name="color">@color/countdown_indicator</item>
</style>
```

works.

I also had to make changes in `preferences.xml` and similar files, where the package name was hard-coded, because in these locations it's actually the Application ID, when resolving Intents:

From:

```
<intent
  android:targetPackage="com.google.android.apps.authenticator2"
  android:targetClass="com.google.android.apps.authenticator.timesync.SettingsTimeCorrectionActivity">
</intent>
```

To:

```
<intent
  android:targetPackage="@string/app_package_name"
  android:targetClass="com.google.android.apps.authenticator.timesync.SettingsTimeCorrectionActivity">
</intent>
```

I had to add a special `app_package_name` to `strings.xml` in all flavors, where I recorded the `applicationId` attribute from the flavor. (If there is another way of referencing the `applicationId`, please let me know!)

Comment: I'm having the same problem for the preferences.xml.
Did you find a better solution?

Comment: @DavidCorsalini Not yet, and I think there currently is no other solution.